# Is it possible to avoid the emission of CO2 and other greenhouse gases from thermoelectric plants?

Tags: thermodynamics, environmental-engineering

Since the deleterious effects of greenhouse gases are well known, I was wondering if it is possible, for example, for thermoelectric plants to avoid this kind of emissions. More exact, I think it should be possible to compress the residual gases at the plant's outlet into tanks. Of course this would imply a more expensive plant and also an higher fuel consumption due to the compression stages, but it would avoid emissions at all. Moreover there also would be the problem to store the tanks once they are full, however I'd like to know if this kind of strategy could be used in a real plant.

Comment: Sounds like a re-write of a homework question or exam essay.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, @SolarMike.  I think I'm not overstepping the mark by telling OP that this concept has a name: "carbon capture and storage"; that NMech's answer describes the most common (but not the only possible) way to achieve the "capture" half; and that the "storage" half is typically not done using tanks (there would need to be a lot more tank factories in the world!)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the concept of [carbon dioxide scrubbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide_scrubber). They are already employed in some coal plants, to mitigate their carbon emissions. It is a costly technology.

There are many technologies available. Usually, at the core of a CO2-scrubbing system used in power plants is an absorber in which a scrubbing solution absorbs the carbon dioxide from the power plant's flue gas at temperatures of about 65$^oC$. The following diagram is a modified version from the following [report](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjmms_g8KvwAhUihv0HHcaqDUIQFjABegQIAhAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.group.rwe%2F-%2Fmedia%2FRWE%2Fdocuments%2F03-unser-portfolio-und-loesungen%2Finnovation-und-technik%2Frwe-innovationszentrum%2Fen%2Fco2-scrubbing.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1TB8QkPZqZug3rwLNPGWHb), which shows the some of the main steps in the process.

[image]

Comment: (Cough!) If that's not your drawing or design then you need to credit it. (This is [site policy](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).) Hit the [edit] link ...